# How to make grid view in j2me

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I am very new in j2me. I want to design following type layout and components.

[image]

Mean I want to arrange my items in gridview. And after clicking on each item I will move to another form.

I am using simple `lcdui`. Please suggest me how can I do this. Means how can I arrange these items in gridview and what items should I use here buttons or something else.

You may provide me some suitable links.

Comment: regarding _suitable links_, since you mention lcdui - consider **['lcdui' tag wiki here at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/lcdui/info "API reference, links to tutorials, popular libraries etc...")**

Comment: I have done this and shared the code at http://smallandadaptive.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/touch-menu.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In J2ME you have two options for UI: Form and Canvas.
Forms are a very simple way to display information without dealing with the graphical side of things, where Canvas is a blank screen and you need to draw the objects and their behaviors.

There is a third way: the guys at Sun has created a framework called ([LWUIT](http://lwuit.java.net/) which stands for Light Weight UI Toolkit). This toolkit provides the simplicity of Forms and the UI control of Canvas.

Hope i helped.